# How to cycle between elements in html using JavaScript using buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hide, show

My problem is that I am trying to cycle between HTML elements using buttons. I want to show one element when I press the associated button and hide the other elements.

My current code uses the show and hide from jquery, and I'm not sure if those are the best for what I'm trying to do. I will ultimately use about 14 buttons and 14 different div elements. An array may work better for what I am trying to do.

This code does not show or hide anything upon button press. I would like the code to show the element associated with each button and hide all other elements.

```js
$(function() {
  $('div1Button').click(function() {
    $('#div1').show();
    $('#div2').hide();
    $('#div3').hide();
  });
  $('div2Button').click(function() {
    $('#div1').hide();
    $('#div2').hide();
    $('#div3').hide();
  });
  $('div3Button').click(function() {
    $('#div1').hide();
    $('#div2').hide();
    $('#div3').show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="div1Button">Div1</button>
<button id="div2Button">Div2</button>
<button id="div3Button">Div3</button>

<div id="div1">
  Hello Im div1
</div>

<div id="div2">
  Hello Im div2
</div>

<div id="div3">
  Hello Im div3
</div>
```

Comment: You're missing the `#` prefix on the id selectors: `$('#div1Button')`. I would also suggest you use common classes instead of unique ids, as it will cut all of your JS down to a single click event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use class for your button and your div instead of id and then use data attribute to target which div will show when button clicked.

Example:

```js
$(".toggleButton").on("click", function() {
  var target = $(this).data("target");
  $(".toggleDiv").hide();  // Hide all div
  $(target).show();  // Show the target div
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="toggleButton" data-target="#div1">Div1</button>
<button class="toggleButton" data-target="#div2">Div2</button>
<button class="toggleButton" data-target="#div3">Div3</button>

<div class="toggleDiv" id="div1">
  Hello Im div1
</div>

<div class="toggleDiv" id="div2">
  Hello Im div2
</div>

<div class="toggleDiv" id="div3">
  Hello Im div3
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the `#` when selecting the buttons.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#div1Button').click(function() {
    $('#div1').show();
    $('#div2').hide();
    $('#div3').hide();
  });
  $('#div2Button').click(function() {
    $('#div1').hide();
    $('#div2').hide();
    $('#div3').hide();
  });
  $('#div3Button').click(function() {
    $('#div1').hide();
    $('#div2').hide();
    $('#div3').show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="div1Button">Div1</button>
<button id="div2Button">Div2</button>
<button id="div3Button">Div3</button>

<div id="div1">
  Hello Im div1
</div>

<div id="div2">
  Hello Im div2
</div>

<div id="div3">
  Hello Im div3
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should give a css class for your shown div, then hide (or give a "hidden" class to) every other div which doesn't have that class.

It will make your code scalable and less redundant.